# Working with temporary tables without prior declaration

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have one stored procedure. I don't know the data type of the result set. I want to avoid prior declaration of table schema.

Now, I want to store the result set of procedure in a temporary table. In pseudo SQL it would look like this:

```
select * into #table1 exec proc_name
```

What would be the real SQL to do it?

Comment: I dont wanna create the schema . like :- create table #table1 (...)

Comment: @Gopal have a look at **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/how-to-select-into-temp-table-from-stored-procedure**

Comment: If you don't know the schema in advance, how can you possibly perform any useful work on the resulting table?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Create a temp tables. Say #temp
Step 2:

```
INSERT INTO #temp
exec proc_name
```

Comment: I will create the temp table based on the output of procedure.In that case temp table will be tighty coupled with result set of proc, which I dont want..Is there any other way?